# idevicedebug compilation fails with "ld: symbol(s) not found"

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

### Environment

- Max OS ( Yosemite )
- xcode 6.3.2
- C/C++ Project

### Use-case

Compile [idevicedebug.c](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/master/tools/idevicedebug.c) as a xcode project

### Problem description

- While compiling the project I get "Undefined symbol for architecture x86_64: "_debug_info_real", referenced type... in idevicedebug.o, ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"
- The project is setup to link against libmobiledevice & libpilist
- using [MachO-View](http://sourceforge.net/projects/machoview/) I can see that the symbol "_debug_info_real" is found at "libimobiledevice"
- I have verified that "libimobiledevice" is linked w/ my project, hence, w/o having it linked I get much more un-resolved externals...

**Why do I get the above mentioned un-resolved symbol error? what am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`Makefile`](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/master/tools/Makefile.am#L83) `idevicedebug.c` depends not only on `libimobiledevice` library but also needs `libinternalcommon` ([`common/debug.h`](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/64b1b1aa1eb53e47e3826f08f0cdc29d43a972b5/common/debug.h#L39) defines `debug_info_real`):

```
idevicedebug_SOURCES = idevicedebug.c
idevicedebug_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS)
idevicedebug_LDFLAGS = $(top_builddir)/common/libinternalcommon.la $(AM_LDFLAGS)
idevicedebug_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libimobiledevice.la
```

Are you linking to this library from Xcode project?

Comment: libimobiledevice.la is a libtool file, I am linking against the corresponding  "libimobiledevice.a"

Comment: What about `libinternalcommon`?

Comment: yup, U R correct, apparently libinternalcommon.a is not being installed and should be taken directly from the compilation folder